# Wordpress woocommerce can't get product item data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I'm trying to get the meta data of a product item in woocommerce. I've tried looping through the object but can't seem to get around. The format looks like below.

```
  array(52) { [0]=> object(WC_Meta_Data)#3939 (2) { ["current_data":protected]=>
  array(3) { ["id"]=> int(2631) ["key"]=> string(14) "slide_template" ["value"]=> string(7)
 "default" } ["data":protected]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(2631) ["key"]=> string(14)...
  ............ etc
```

I've tried looping through to no avail using the following method  to get the items.

```
 $theitem = ($product->get_meta_data() ); 
 var_dump($theitem);
```

How can I loop through to get the item value? I've tried `foreach` and even a bit of indexing, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r()`. Does it give more than `var_dump()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as follows to get your meta data under loop -

```
foreach ($product->get_meta_data() as $index => $data) {
    echo $data->key . ' :' . $data->value . '<br/>';
}
```